# Ajax handler json response on global response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

on my project I have hundred of calls ajax where some of them have a response of status of login in json.

If the user in not logged i'll receive.

```
{status : no-log }
```

Now i would like know how i can check if the status is "no-log" on all my requests ajax without put for each function the if statement, it's useful for show a modal of login example. I took a look $.ajaxSuccess() but i think it doesn't what i'm looking for. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Global ajax complete handler might be able to do the trick:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    //global ajaxy stuff
});
```

Comment: with ajaxComplete can i access to my response json? I'll try it soon

Comment: @Gilbert -- wasn't 100% sure if you could, but I figured it was worth a try.

Comment: I tried it but how i thought it doesn't work, thank you the same for your help